# Detect links in messages in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm new to discord.js. I'm trying to check if a message contains a link like "Hi, I'm from discord.gg/xxxxx and now I'll spam my link".
How can I check if the message contain the link?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am unsure if you want to check for discord invite links specifically, or if you want to check for all links. Either way, you can use `message.content.includes`.

Example:

```
bot.on('message', (message) => { //whenever a message is sent
  if (message.content.includes('discord.gg/'||'discordapp.com/invite/')) { //if it contains an invite link
    message.delete() //delete the message
      .then(message.channel.send('Link Deleted:\n**Invite links are not permitted on this server**'))
  }
})
```

Comment: It is important to include discordapp.com/invite in your code as well, because links like that can be used to bypass your link-filtering.

Comment: Nowadays you must also include `discord.com/invite` as those are valid invites that will be embedded.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
bot.on(`message`, async message => {
    const bannedWords = [`discord.gg`, `.gg/`, `.gg /`, `. gg /`, `. gg/`, `discord .gg /`, `discord.gg /`, `discord .gg/`, `discord .gg`, `discord . gg`, `discord. gg`, `discord gg`, `discordgg`, `discord gg /`]
    try {
        if (bannedWords.some(word => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(word))) {
            if (message.author.id === message.guild.ownerID) return;
            await message.delete();
            await message.channel.send(`You cannot send invites to other Discord servers`);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

(There was a missing ")")

Answer (score 1):

I find this is the best:

```
let regx = /^((?:https?:)?\/\/)?((?:www|m)\.)? ((?:discord\.gg|discordapp\.com))/g
let cdu = regx.test(message.content.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, ''))
```

Tell me if it works!

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing works but you don't need `.then()` just leave the `message.channel.send()` as it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this using [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) (RegEX)

**Example**:

```
// The message to check for a Discord link
var message = "Hi, please join discord.gg/a2dsc for cool conversations";

// The message will be tested on "discord.gg/{any character or digit}"
var containsDiscordUrl = message.test(/discord.gg\/\w*\d*);

// If the test has found a URL..
if (containsDiscordUrl) { // ... Do something }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let regexp = /^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/\S*)?$/;
```

I think this is helping you.

**Edit:**

`(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?` - http, https, or ftp

`(?:(?! ... )(?! ... )(?! ... ))` - These are negative lookup statements, used to ensure that the IP address does not fall into specific reserved ranges.

`(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])`| `(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}` | `(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))` - check IPv4

`(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)` - check domain name

`(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*` - check sub domain

`(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,}))` - check top-level domain

`(?::\d{2,5})?` - cehck port number

`(?:\/\S*)?$` - check optional path

**Use this regex for discord invite check**

```
\b(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:discord\.gg|discord\.com/invite)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\b
```

Comment: We assume that by posting an answer you are trying to help ;-)
First, it helps to explain why your answer is better or different from other older answers.
And, it looks like you are adding to another answer so this is not an answer by itself.
Maybe this should be a comment on that other answer? Or you could say "I would improve on the answer by <author> by ..."
Keep in mind that the order of answers changes over time, so you cannot assume your answer is just above or just below the one you are improving on.